# AEM package manager returning html instead of xml [ERROR] Missing response status information in response:

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, adobe, aem

I have a maven multi module project set up for an AEM application:

- core
- ui.apps
- it.launcher
- it.tests
- ui.workflows (added more recently)

The application is deployed through Jenkins via a Maven build using the 0.0.24 version of the com.day.jcr.vault content-package-maven-plugin:

`mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage (-D... [admin creds] -D... [server info])`

Intermittently, the Jenkins build will fail because the deployment of ui.workflows to `http://{server}.{port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp` will fail with the following message:

**[ERROR] Missing response status information in response:**

Checking in the logs of successful and unsuccessful deployments, I can see that the *successful* deployment requests returns an *XML* response that begins with

`<crx version="1.4.1" user="admin" workspace="crx.default">`

and ends with

`Package installed in 4098ms.
                </log>
            </data>
        <status code="200">ok</status>
    </response>
</crx>`

The *unsuccessful* deployment requests returns an *HTML* response that begins with

`<html>
    <head>
        <title>Content modified /crx/packmgr/service.jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Content modified /crx/packmgr/service.jsp</h1>
        <table>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>Status</td>
                   <td><div id="Status">200</div></td>
               </tr>`

I surmise that the request to the service endpoint in AEM was successful but that the plugin could not parse the HTML response. It looks like AEM in 6.2 is moving away from the /crx/packmgr/service.jsp endpoint, as well as XML responses in this documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/how_to/package_manager.html)

In the [Adobe Nexus Repo for the maven plugin](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/jcr/vault/content-package-maven-plugin/), there is a new version (0.5), which is a significant leap in version number from the previous number, and also coincides with the AEM 6.2 version release (April 2016) but I cannot find any documentation on how to configure the new plugin.

If anyone has experienced this issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

For help on the latest plugin you could do following -

```
mvn com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.5.1:help
```

This will give you list of goals available with new plugin. Given that you are looking into installing the package, the goal to get details will be `install`, you could type following command to get the details for configuring the goal -

```
mvn com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.5.1:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=install
```

This will give you configuration details, something like -

> [INFO] Adobe Content Package Maven Plugin 0.5.1   Maven Plugin
>   supporting creation of content packages and controlling the   package
>   manager on a remote system.
>
> content-package:install   Install a Content Package on a remote CRX or
>   Communique 5 system.
>
> Available parameters:
>
> ```
> artifact
>   A string of the form groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging].
>   User property: vault.artifact
>
> artifactId
>   The artifactId of the artifact to install
>   User property: vault.artifactId
>
> failOnError (Default: false)
>   If true, fail the build if there is an error while installing.
>   User property: vault.failOnError
>
> groupId
>   The groupId of the artifact to install
>   User property: vault.groupId
>
> install (Default: true)
>   Whether to install (unpack) the uploaded package automatically or not.
>   User property: vault.install
>
> name (Default: ${project.artifactId})
>   The name of the content package
>   User property: vault.name
>
> packageFile (Default:
> ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip)
>   The name of the content package file to install on the target system. If
>   not set, the primary artifact of the project is considered the content
>   package to be installed.
>   User property: vault.file
>
> packaging (Default: zip)
>   The packaging of the artifact to install
>   User property: vault.packaging
>
> password (Default: admin)
>   The password to authenticate against the remote CRX system.
>   Required: Yes
>   User property: vault.password
>
> relaxedSSLCheck (Default: false)
>
>   User property: vault.relaxedSSLCheck
>
> repositoryId (Default: temp)
>   The id of the repository from which we'll download the artifact
>   User property: vault.repoId
>
> repositoryUrl
>   The url of the repository from which we'll download the artifact
>   User property: vault.repoUrl
>
> serverId
>   The server id with which to get the username and password from the user's
>   settings file.
>   User property: vault.serverId
>
> serviceURL (Default: http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json)
>
>   Required: Yes
>   User property: vault.serviceURL
>
> targetURL (Default: http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp)
>   The URL to the HTTP service API of the CRX package manager. See HTTP
>   Service Interface for details on this interface.
>   Required: Yes
>   User property: vault.targetURL
>
> timeout (Default: 5)
>   The connection timeout to set when communicating with the package manager
>   service. Default value is 5 seconds. Value is specified in seconds.
>   User property: vault.timeout
>
> useProxy (Default: true)
>   Setting this to false disables considering the use of any of the active
>   proxies configured in the Maven Settings. By default the first active
>   proxy configuration in the Maven Settings is used to proxy any request to
>   the package manager.
>   User property: vault.useProxy
>
> userId (Default: admin)
>   The user name to authenticate as against the remote CRX system.
>   Required: Yes
>   User property: vault.userId
>
> verbose (Default: false)
>   Enable verbose logging when set to true.
>   User property: vault.verbose
>
> version
>   The version of the artifact to install
>   User property: vault.version
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for my multimodule project:

- module 1: simple content
- module 2: simple content, assets and bundle
- module 3: simple content

Packages for these modules were installed in the order shown above and it seemed to be the issue.

It turned out that the problem occurred when installing the third package and in `error.log` there was a problem with some workflows for assets. I don't know what's the exact reason, but changing the order of packages actually helped, so what I had to do is to install the package with assets and bundle **at the end**. You may consider a similar solution depending on your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old problem but we encountered this issue recently. Updating to version 0.5.24 of content-package-maven-plugin resolves the issue.

The deploy profile on local machines works ok but failed in CI environment for which I'll create another story and link it here.

Comment: I also had to add `<allowIndexDefinitions>true</allowIndexDefinitions>` to the plugin `configurations`

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
   <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
   <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>install-package</id>
          <goals>
             <goal>install</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <version>0.0.24</version>
       <extensions>true</extensions>
       <configuration>
           <failOnError>true</failOnError>
           <username>${crx.username}</username>
           <password>${crx.password}</password>
       </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: The above should fix your issue. It fixed mine.